# preview buffers used for taking picture too?

Tags: android, camera

I'm working on a custom camera app, and when I try to take higher resolution pictures, my jpeg callback is never called. I run logcat, and I see this message:

E/Camera-JNI(14689): Manually set buffer was too small! Expected 1473253 bytes, but got 768000!

As far as I know, I don't manually set the buffer size for taking a picture, but I do call addCallbackBuffer for capturing preview images.

Are those same buffers used for taking a picture as well as the preview? The description in the android developer docs says "Adds a pre-allocated buffer to the preview callback buffer queue." which uses the word "preview", so I wouldn't think it has anything to do with the takePicture().

So where is this manually allocated buffer it speaks of coming from?

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I need "YES" answer:)